# No se encuentra la función pública de un objeto

Tags: c++

Tengo un objeto `arreglo` que me envuelve un búfer de datos y me permite acceder a sub-partes (vistas) del búfer como si fueran otro búfer.

Por ejemplo, declaro un `arreglo` de 100 elementos:

```
arreglo a(100);

// Inicializo los 100 elementos con valores del 0 al 99...
for (arreglo::indice indice = 0; indice < a.tamanyo(); ++indice)
    a[indice] = indice;

// Creo una vista del arreglo sobre los elementos del 50 al 59
arreglo::vista v = a.vista(50, 10);

// Modifico los elementos de la vista
for (arreglo::indice indice = 0; indice < v.tamanyo(); ++indice)
    v[indice] = indice;
```

Ésta es la clase `arreglo`:

```
struct arreglo
{
    using tipo = std::uint32_t;
    using indice = std::int32_t;

    struct vista
    {
        vista(tipo *const a_inicio, indice a_tamanyo) :
            m_inicio  { a_inicio  },
            m_tamanyo { a_tamanyo }
        {}

              tipo &operator[](indice a_indice)       { return m_inicio[a_indice]; }
        const tipo &operator[](indice a_indice) const { return m_inicio[a_indice]; }

        indice tamanyo() const { return m_tamanyo; }

    private:
        tipo *const m_inicio  { nullptr };
        const indice m_tamanyo{         };
    };

    arreglo(indice a_tamanyo) :
        m_datos  { new tipo[a_tamanyo] },
        m_tamanyo{ a_tamanyo           }
    {
        std::fill(m_datos, m_datos + a_tamanyo, tipo{});
    }

    ~arreglo() { delete [] m_datos; }

          tipo &operator[](indice a_indice)       { return m_datos[a_indice]; }
    const tipo &operator[](indice a_indice) const { return m_datos[a_indice]; }

    indice tamanyo() const { return m_tamanyo; }

    vista vista(indice a_inicio, indice a_longitud)
    {
        return { m_datos + a_inicio, a_longitud };
    }

private:
    tipo *const m_datos   { nullptr };
    const indice m_tamanyo{         };
};
```

Pero cuando uso la clase me falla al compilar:

```
arreglo a(100);

for (arreglo::indice indice = 0; indice < a.tamanyo(); ++indice)
    a[indice] = indice;

/* error: invalid use of non-static member function
   'arreglo::vista arreglo::vista(arreglo::indice, arreglo::indice)' */
arreglo::vista v1 = a.vista(50, 10); // Elementos del 50 al 59
//       ^~~~~

for (arreglo::indice indice = 0; indice < v1.tamanyo(); ++indice)
    v1[indice] = indice;

/* error: invalid use of non-static member function
   'arreglo::vista arreglo::vista(arreglo::indice, arreglo::indice)' */
arreglo::vista v2 = a.vista(45, 10); // Elementos del 45 al 54
//       ^~~~~

for (arreglo::indice indice = 0; indice < v2.tamanyo(); ++indice)
    std::cout << v2[indice] << ' ';
```

No entiendo por qué no encuentra la función `vista` si forma parte de la clase `arreglo` y es pública.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema no es que no encuentre la función `arreglo::vista` si no que confunde el sub-objeto `arreglo::vista` con la función `arreglo::vista`.

Este es uno de los pocos casos en que el especificador de objeto (`class`, `struct`, o `union`) es necesario en C++, pues permite desambiguar una situación ambigua, veámoslo:

```
arreglo a(100);

for (arreglo::indice indice = 0; indice < a.tamanyo(); ++indice)
    a[indice] = indice;

  struct arreglo::vista v1 = a.vista(50, 10); // Elementos del 50 al 59
//^^^^^^

for (arreglo::indice indice = 0; indice < v1.tamanyo(); ++indice)
    v1[indice] = indice;

  struct arreglo::vista v2 = a.vista(45, 10); // Elementos del 45 al 54
//^^^^^^

for (arreglo::indice indice = 0; indice < v2.tamanyo(); ++indice)
    std::cout << v2[indice] << ' ';
```

Pero el compilador ya sabe que `a.vista` devuelve una `struct arreglo::vista`, así que no sería necesario especificarlo (y queda muy verboso), por lo tanto podemos *mejorar* el código de la siguiente manera:

```
arreglo a(100);

for (arreglo::indice indice = 0; indice < a.tamanyo(); ++indice)
    a[indice] = indice;

  auto v1 = a.vista(50, 10); // Elementos del 50 al 59
//^^^^

for (arreglo::indice indice = 0; indice < v1.tamanyo(); ++indice)
    v1[indice] = indice;

  auto v2 = a.vista(45, 10); // Elementos del 45 al 54
//^^^^

for (arreglo::indice indice = 0; indice < v2.tamanyo(); ++indice)
    std::cout << v2[indice] << ' ';
```